# OneSignal how to send Push to specific device - ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, uuid, onesignal

I want onesignal to be able to send push notification to a specific device.

1. How do I capture the device id of the device ?
2. And what API do I use to push to that specific device ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a copy of OneSignal's guide on sending a notification to an individual device:

**If you're looking to send notifications to only your test devices:**

1. Tag your devices with a unique tag with `sendTag`.

   - Example: `OneSignal.sendTag("is_test", "true")`
   - For an exact example see OneSignal's [API Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#section-how-do-i-send-a-notification-to-a-single-user-) for the SDK you're using.
2. Create a new Segment on the OneSignal dashboard named test devices.
3. Press "Add Filter" and select "User Tag" as the "Filter Type".
4. Enter is_test equal to true.

   - The values you used in step 1.
5. When creating a new notification, remove "All" and add your test devices segment.

**If you're looking to send notifications to a specific user device:
(Can be used for User-to-User notifications)**

1. Get the user's `player_id` with the `getIdsAvailable` SDK method.

   - See OneSignal's [API Reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#section-how-do-i-send-a-notification-to-a-single-user-) for the SDK you're using for example code.
   - For testing you can use the 'Player ID' shown on the user page on the dashboard.

     - You can force kill your app and open it again to bring your device to the top of the list.
2. Send the `userId` from the `getIdsAvailable` callback if the pushToken is not null or blank to your server.
3. Set `include_player_ids` to the userId on the PostNotification SDK method or on the [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference) REST API call.

Comment: thank you very much. just a small question, OneSignal.sendTag("is_test", "true") - the params are key and value. is the key the deviceid, what is the value for ?

Comment: @Axil sendTags lets you assign custom key/value pairs to a user. So you could do things like sendTag("age","31") or sendTag("city","San Francisco"), or in this case sendTag("is_test","true"). Next you can target your notifications to users who have or don't have a specific tag and value.

Comment: thanks. actually, i cant find the part from the server side on how to get the player_id/device id from the tags that were sent by the mobile.

Comment: To get a user id:
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
        status.subscriptionStatus.userId

Comment: One thing i dont understand how can you get somebody elses Player id?  Isnt it stored only on his own device? So getidsavailable returns only your own id?